# Docusign - how can I make sure a signer signs all the documents in one envelop

Tags: docusignapi

When I try to create an envelop with multiple documents, I have a question.
How can I make sure a signer signs all the documents?

For example, if I create an envelop with file1 and file2, the signer will receive a combined document to sign (file1 up and file2 down), but I think a signer can just click "finish" when he signs file1 without signing file2.

Is there a solution for this?

#####UPDATE

Answer -> [Docusign - Free-From Signing on multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484838/docusign-free-from-signing-on-multiple-documents)

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, Free Form signing is really just a fallback - only suitable in limited circumstances where you *really* trust the signer to get everything in good order.

In general, it's best to guide your signer by placing tags: either through a template, through the API directly, or via PDF Form Field conversion. More info and links to in-depth examples are available on the DocuSign Developer Center: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/