# Docusign - Free-From Signing on multiple documents

Tags: docusignapi

My case is that I create an envelope with multiple documents, and I choose to use free-form signing.

But I find when I finish free-form signing on the first document, I can click on the "finish" button, without signing the other documents.

I wonder whether there is a setting that I can click the "finish" button only if I finish free-form signing on all the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, free form is completely "free form".
If you want them to sign all documents, put tags ahead of time on all documents.
The documents are all part of a single envelope and the envelope is the basic unit that needs to have at least one tab (signing element) on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it!
A small following question, is there a way that I can make sure the signer views all the documents?
In my case above, the signer can directly free-from sign on the first page of the first document and click "finish" without viewing other documents.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-adding-initials-each-page-each-document-your-envelope if you are developing an integration, you can do this from code

Comment: There's another way to do this Arbor. In Signing Settings there's a setting that forces the user to scroll and see all the documents. There's a drop-down in the Settings->Signing Settings that you can use to require them to navigate to each and every page. Just found out about it.